# Why is upload date the same as publish date?

Tags: date, upload, youtube-api, publish

I've uploaded video to Youtube one day as a private one and after a week I've set it to public status. Yet, the Youtube API call returns the same date in **published** and **uploaded** tags which is the date of publishing the video. Why the uploaded date got changed to publish date, while the upload was done about a week before publishing the video? Is there something wrong with the API or maybe I missed something?

I'm using this call to get the data: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/MY_VIDEO_ID?v=2&prettyprint=true

Answer (score 2):

You told, At first it was kept as private video. That type of video can be shared/viewed by you or certain number of people. Youtube will considered the video type (public/private) and that date will be considered. For every private video it is considered as Published.